# Java Runnable Queue

Tags: java, multithreading

I need peer reviews of the critical piece of code below.

This class maintain a queue of runnable objets, and ensure they are executed sequentially, that is, start one new after the previous one is completed until there is no more task in the queue.

I'm pretty sure it does, but I'm must be absolutely sure it behave as intented.

Many thanks !

```
public final class RunnableQueue {

    private final ExecutorService m_executorService;
    private final Queue<Runnable> m_runnables;
    private final Runnable m_loop;

    public RunnableQueue(ExecutorService executorService) {
        m_executorService = executorService;
        m_runnables = new LinkedList<Runnable>();

        m_loop = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                Runnable l_runnable = current();

                while(l_runnable != null) {
                    l_runnable.run();
                    l_runnable = next();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private Runnable current() {
        synchronized (m_runnables) {
            return m_runnables.peek();
        }
    }

    private Runnable next() {
        synchronized (m_runnables) {
            m_runnables.remove();
            return m_runnables.peek();
        }
    }

    public void enqueue(Runnable runnable) {
        if(runnable != null) {
            synchronized (m_runnables) {
                m_runnables.add(runnable);
                if(m_runnables.size() == 1) {
                    m_executorService.execute(m_loop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Basicaly, there will be hundreds of `RunnableQueue` instanciated using the same `ThreadPool` and each `Runnable` executed may add other `Runnable` in other `RunnableQueue`.

So, new `Runnable` will be added to the `RunnableQueue` while it runs...

Comment: Sorry, this may be interesting, but it is **Not a real question**

Comment: If you are looking for critique then; 1) Its very complicated, much more than it needs to be, which leads to 2) There are no comments or javadocs explaining what it does, how it does it or why it does it. Finally 3) When I see variables like `m_executorService` it makes by blood boil, any type of hungarian notation, especially with underscores was made obselete by modern IDEs about 10 years ago.

Answer (score 10):

Any reason you don't use fixed thread pool with a single thread?

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

`submit`ting `Runnable`s to `service` will do exactly what you want as the service operates off a queue.

Comment: @Nicolas that is mandatory to uphold your requirement `ensure they are executed sequentially, that is, start one new after the previous one is completed`

Comment: but I think @Nicolas plans to submit say 5 RunnableQueue instances to an ExecutorService with 3 threads... so fewer threads... which (I agree) is a silly notion because he is adding a lot of complexity for no value.

Comment: Has I said in the edit of my post, there will be _hundreds_ of queues, and one thread pool of, say, 10 threads max. Think of one queue per connection on a big application server, with Runnable being requests to process. Requests may be queued at any time by the network thread, and must be executed sequentially for a given connection.

Answer (score 8):

Obvious question: Why do you use `Runnable`s (threads) while you do not want to execute those threads in parallel?

If the idea is to execute the *items* in the queue in parallel to something else, you could consider using only one thread (runnable) that executes all *commands* in the queue in a sequence:

```
private Queue<Command> queue = initQueue();

public run() {
  while(!stop) {
    Command nextCommand = queue.pop();
    nextCommand.execute();
  }
}
```

`Command` is a custom interface with just one single method. (Note: this simple example expects that the queue is never empty)

Comment: For clarity, I'm must agree with the introduction of your Command interface.